# Syntax error after adding a variable into Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome

I used a Jquery script to make a drop-down div.

```
$("#top<?php echo $this->$i?>").click(function(){
        $("#down<?php echo $this->$i?>").slideToggle("slow","swing",500);
      });
    });
```

this is give a syntax error in google chrome. In inspector it's showing as "#top
 .Bellow one is work fine.

```
$("#top<?php echo "one"?>).click(function(){
        $("#down<?php echo "two"?>").slideToggle("slow","swing",500);
      });
    });
```

why is this happening and if I have made a mistake how to fix it.

This is my phtml file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#top<?php echo $this->i;?>").click(function(){
        $("#down<?php echo $this->i;?>").slideToggle("slow","swing",500);
      });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="R_booking_container">
    <h1 id="R_booking_header">Recently Added Bookings</h1>
    <div id="left_pane">
        <ul class="left_pane_ul">
            <li class="left_pane_button"><a href="#">Facility Bookings</a></li>
            <li class="left_pane_button"><a href="#">Equipment Bookings</a></li>
            <li class="left_pane_button"><a href="#">Recurring Bookings</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="right_pane">
    <?php   $datas = $this->data_array;
            $i = 0;
            foreach($datas as $datas) { 
            extract ($datas);
            $i++?>
        <div class="booking_details" id="top_box" id="top<?php echo $i?>">
            <h1 id="event_name"><?php echo $event_name;?></h1>
            <hr id="event_line"/>
            <div id="to_more_info">
                <span class="date_time">Date: <?php echo $time;?></span>
                <span class="date_time">Time: <?php echo $time;?></span>
            </div>
            <div id="drop_down_info" id="down<?php echo $i?>">
                <table id="more_b_info" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info"><span class="b_info">Booked By:</span></td>
                        <td class="info"><span class="b_info"><?php echo $booked_by;?></span></td>
                        <td class="info"><span class="b_info">Booking ID:</span></td>
                        <td class="info"><span class="b_info"><?php echo $booking_id;?></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info"><span class="b_info">Requested User:</span></td>
                        <td class="info"><span class="b_info"><?php echo $requested_user;?></span></td>
                        <td class="info"><span class="b_info">Payment Due Date:</span></td>
                        <td class="info"><span class="b_info"><?php echo $payment_due_date;?></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info"><span class="b_info">Booking Status:</span></td>
                        <td class="info"><span class="b_info"><?php echo $booking_status;?></span></td>
                        <td class="info"><span class="b_info">Sponsored Booking:</span></td>
                        <td class="info"><span class="b_info"><?php echo $sponsored_booking;?></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post what the *actual output* is?

Comment: Hard to help without seeing the output :P

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo $this->$i?>
```

Should actually be

```
<?php echo $this->i ?>
```

Without the `$` sign for `i`

Comment: and a trailing semicolon no?

Comment: Nope that's not a must before `?>` Although I always use it but I deliberately didn't add it here so people don't start saying no you didn't have to add that etc etc :)

Comment: I doesn't work without $ symbol or with a ;. Syntax error has removed. but the script doesn't work.

Comment: That's a different story then. Your PHP error was only that. Now you have to see the output HTML that this is generating and debug *why* is it not working when its not producing any error either.

Comment: It's not echoing i in inspector. What can be the issues? I have defined $i in same page.

Comment: If the variable is `$i` then why are you using `$this->$i`? Need to see your PHP code which populates the value of `$i`

Comment: I added my code into question. please look at it. :-)